# How to use find command in OS X terminal to search for folders?

Tags: macos, terminal

Im trying to search for folders in the OS X terminal. Is there any way to filter the find results for folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there any way to filter the find results for folders?

To list all the directory and sub-directory names:

```
find . -type d
```

---

#### Further reading

- [find](http://ss64.com/osx/find.html) - Search a folder hierarchy for filename(s) that meet a desired criteria.

Answer (score -1):

the ls command can find directories too

ls -l | grep ^d

ls is list 
-l is for the long listing format but that's optional 
grep means only match d which means only matches lines that start with d

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?